Searching over multiple columns and row to see if value exist in a table for Excel VBA
Hello everyone I am doing a project and need some VBA coding assistance to automate this requirement.

Requirement:

Outcome is to perform a check for a particular users under the same 'category' we need to identify outliers

Outliers means either team member or team member+1 is not discoverable in any of the values (rows/columns) under the same category table.

If there are any outliers for a particular zone, would like to record down the result of either outlier or not an outlier

Check will continue down for other different categories for the remaining table.


I've been spending 5 days smashing my head and studying VBA, but I would really appreciate for some help here and guidance.

Try using Macro Recorder.

Assuming that the table is in the top-left of the Worksheet (i.e. "Zone" is in Cell $A$1):
With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Columns(5)
    .Formula = "=IF(COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)+COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$D:$D,$C1)+COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$D1)+COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$D:$D,$D1)<3, ""Outlier"", ""Not an Outlier"")"
    .Calculate
    .Value = .Value
    .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Result"
End With

All this does is drop the following formula (with fill-down) into the "Results" column, calculate the result, then turn that into text rather than a formula (and replace the "Result" heading):
=IF(COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$C1)+COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$D:$D,$C1)+COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$C:$C,$D1)+COUNTIFS($B:$B,$B1,$D:$D,$D1)<3, "Outlier", "Not an Outlier")

And all that that does is add up how many times either Team Members appear in columns C or D for that Category (using 4 COUNTIFS).  If it's more than 2, then it's not an outlier.
(2 being the result for the current row, since "Team Member" appears in Column C (1) and not in Column D (1+0), and "Team Member+1" does not appear in Column D (1+0+0) but does appear in Column D (1+0+0+1))
Of course, since it's just an Excel formula, you can also skip the VBA and just use the formula if you prefer…

Thank you so much for quick reply. Quick question what does currentRegion.Columns(5) mean? is it that we are dealing with total of 5 range of columns?

@BlakeJPark Breaking it down: ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1) is cell A1 in the current Worksheet. The Range.CurrentRegion property expands that to the full block of contiguous cells that it is part of (i.e. the entire table).  Then the Range.Columns property means that we are only working on the fifth column of the table (i.e. the "Result" column). It's like saying "Start in your sitting room, look at the whole street, then go to the fifth house".

Identify Rows Where All Members Occur Only Once Per Category

Sub IdentifyOutliers()

    ' Define constants.
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const UNIQUE_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Dim MEMBER_COLUMNS() As Variant: MEMBER_COLUMNS = VBA.Array(3, 4)
    Const RESULT_COLUMN As Long = 5
    Const RESULT_YES As String = "Outlier"
    Const RESULT_NO As String = "Nope"
    Const DEBUG_PRINT_DICTIONARY As Boolean = False
    ' Reference the workbook and worksheet.
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    ' Reference the data range.
    
    Dim rg As Range, RowsCount As Long, ColumnsCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        RowsCount = .Rows.Count - 1
        If RowsCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' no data
        ColumnsCount = Application _
            .Max(UNIQUE_COLUMN, MEMBER_COLUMNS, RESULT_COLUMN)
        Set rg = .Resize(RowsCount, ColumnsCount).Offset(1)
    End With

    ' Return the values of the data range in an array.
    Dim sData() As Variant: sData = rg.Value

    ' Return the distinct values from the unique ('Category') column
    ' in the keys of a dictionary. Each corresponding item will hold
    ' another dictionary whose keys will hold the members, while
    ' the correspoding items will hold the count of each member.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim Value As Variant, r As Long, uStr As String, mStr As String, c As Long
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        uStr = sData(r, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        If Not dict.Exists(uStr) Then
            Set dict(uStr) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            dict(uStr).CompareMode = vbTextCompare
        End If
        For c = 0 To UBound(MEMBER_COLUMNS)
            mStr = sData(r, MEMBER_COLUMNS(c))
            dict(uStr)(mStr) = dict(uStr)(mStr) + 1
        Next c
    Next r
    
    ' Optionally, return the vales of the dictionary in the Immediate window.
    ' Note that the Immediate window can hold only 200 rows at the time.
    If DEBUG_PRINT_DICTIONARY Then
        Dim oKey As Variant, iKey As Variant
        For Each oKey In dict.Keys
            Debug.Print oKey
            For Each iKey In dict(oKey).Keys
                Debug.Print iKey, dict(oKey)(iKey)
            Next iKey
        Next oKey
    End If
    
    ' Define the destination array.
    Dim dData() As Variant: ReDim dData(1 To RowsCount, 1 To 1)
    
    ' Loop through the rows of the source array and using the information
    ' in the dictionary, identify the rows where all (both) members
    ' occured only once for the current category.
    
    Dim IsOutlier As Boolean
    
    For r = 1 To RowsCount
        uStr = sData(r, UNIQUE_COLUMN)
        IsOutlier = True
        For c = 0 To UBound(MEMBER_COLUMNS)
            mStr = sData(r, MEMBER_COLUMNS(c))
            If dict(uStr)(mStr) > 1 Then
                IsOutlier = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next c
        If IsOutlier Then
            dData(r, 1) = RESULT_YES
        Else
            dData(r, 1) = RESULT_NO
        End If
    Next r
    
    ' Return the values from the destination array in the destination range.
    rg.EntireRow.Columns(RESULT_COLUMN).Value = dData
    
    ' Inform.
    MsgBox "Outliers identified.", vbInformation
    
End Sub

Result in the Immdiate Window (Ctrl+G)
Football
Sue            3 
Liam           1 
Mary           2 
Don            5 
Peter          1 
Jenny          1 
Zoe            1 
Marc           3 
James          2 
John           1 
BasketBall
James          1 
Mary           1 
Peter          3 
Don            3 
Marc           1 
John           1 
Sue            1 
Zoe            1 
BaseBall
Peter          1 
John           1 
Jenny          1 
Don            1 
Marc           2 
Zoe            1 
Sue            1 



The following table was created using Table To Markdown




Zone
Category
Team Member
Team Member + 1
Result




1
Football
Sue
Liam
Nope


2
BasketBall
James
Mary
Outlier


3
Football
Mary
Don
Nope


4
Football
Peter
Jenny
Outlier


5
Football
Sue
Zoe
Nope


6
BasketBall
Peter
Don
Nope


7
Football
Don
Sue
Nope


8
BaseBall
Peter
John
Outlier


9
Football
Marc
Don
Nope


10
BaseBall
Jenny
Don
Outlier


11
BasketBall
Marc
John
Outlier


12
Football
Don
Marc
Nope


13
BasketBall
Peter
Sue
Nope


14
BasketBall
Peter
Don
Nope


15
Football
Don
Marc
Nope


16
Football
James
John
Nope


17
BaseBall
Marc
Zoe
Nope


18
BaseBall
Sue
Marc
Nope


19
Football
James
Mary
Nope


20
BasketBall
Zoe
Don
Nope



